# How can I make array of array to just simple associative array by swapping the keys?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I make a multidimensional array like the first key becomes the root key and the second key becomes the value?

Is there any build in function for this, if yes then which one?

**My Input array is:**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key] => key1
            [label] => value1
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [key] => key2
            [label] => value2
        )

    [key3] => Array
        (
            [key] => key3
            [label] => value3
        )

    [key4] => Array
        (
            [key] => key4
            [label] => value4
        )

)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array (
    [key1] => value1

    [key2] => value2

    [key3] => value3

    [key4] => value4

)
```

*I can do it with iterating the for loop on array, but just looking for any existing function(s)!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, indeed, do this without a loop with some native functions.

On top of my head:

```php
$combined = array_combine( array_keys( $input ), array_column( $input, 'label' ) );
```

Or if you want to take key from the item:

```php
$combined = array_column( $input, 'label', 'key' );
```

Comment: Second one also worked for me, which one is better? for sure second option still want your thoughts...

Comment: It depends where you want keys to come from, to preserve keys from original array or to take some value from every item as a key to use. For your given example data these two should be the same (since keys of the array are the same as `key` values in items).

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this combination of core array functions,

```
$input = array_combine(array_keys($input), array_column($input, 'label'));
```

[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values
[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Answer (score 1):

You can try [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = // .. your array
$result = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item){
    $carry[$item->key] = $item->value;
    return $carry;
},[]);
```